# press a button in tableviewCell and perform another controller

Tags: swift, uibutton, show, uistoryboardsegue

I have one UIButton in a tableviewcell which setted "show segue" in the mainStoryBoard. And I want to press this button and perform new controller, so how can I do this?

Comment: Create callback  either delegate  to get Action of button thereafter perform communication between viewControllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//there are  many ways to do it 1 of the way is:
// take the button outlet in tableviewcell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell2 : cellname = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellname") as! cellname
    cell2.addAddressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openNewVC), for: .touchUpInside) 
    return cell2
}

func openNewVC(){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Identifiername", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: or u can make delegates and do the task

Comment: Oh..that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom delegate in tableview cell,

Follow the below link for that,

https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Now, In view controller, inside delegate function use

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self)
```